# Как узнать производителя JVM?

Tags: java, jvm

Как узнать производителя **JVM**? Как я понимаю, существует несколько производителей **JVM**: *Oracle* (Oracle Hotspot), сообщество свободного программного обеспечения (OpenJDK),  *IBM* (IBM J9),  *Azul Systems* (Zing) и другие. Как (по пакету jdk) можно узнать, чья версия **JVM** используется?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
System.getProperty("java.vendor");
System.getProperty("java.vm.name");
```

Answer (score 1):

См. статический метод [`System.getProperties()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties()), который возвращает объект [`Properties`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) с текущими значениями свойств системы, среди которых `java.vm.**`.

Описание возвращаемых значений:

```
Key                               Description of Associated Value
-----------------------------------------------------------------
java.version                      Java Runtime Environment version
java.vendor                       Java Runtime Environment vendor
java.vendor.url                   Java vendor URL
java.home                         Java installation directory
java.vm.specification.version     Java Virtual Machine specification version
java.vm.specification.vendor      Java Virtual Machine specification vendor
java.vm.specification.name        Java Virtual Machine specification name
java.vm.version                   Java Virtual Machine implementation version
java.vm.vendor                    Java Virtual Machine implementation vendor
java.vm.name                      Java Virtual Machine implementation name
java.specification.version        Java Runtime Environment specification version
java.specification.vendor         Java Runtime Environment specification vendor
java.specification.name           Java Runtime Environment specification name
java.class.version                Java class format version number
java.class.path                   Java class path
java.library.path                 List of paths to search when loading libraries
java.io.tmpdir                    Default temp file path
java.compiler                     Name of JIT compiler to use
java.ext.dirs                     Path of extension directory or directories
os.name                           Operating system name
os.arch                           Operating system architecture
os.version                        Operating system version
file.separator                    File separator ("/" on UNIX)
path.separator                    Path separator (":" on UNIX)
line.separator                    Line separator ("\n" on UNIX)
user.name                         User's account name
user.home                         User's home directory
user.dir                          User's current working directory
```

---

См. [Передача JVM параметров (аргументов) “изнутри”](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/714727/236980).

Answer (score 0):

Или  из  командной  строки  java -fullversion

Comment: Установлено Liberica JDK 11 (от Bellsoft), `java -fullversion` показывает только `openjdk full version "11.0.8+10-LTS"`

Comment: OOps. Liberica? Я не знал такую