# Передача JVM параметров (аргументов) "изнутри"

Tags: java, память, jvm

Как можно установить параметры `JVM` (объём памяти и тд...) без использования запуска через `.bat` файл? Возможно ли это без использования `launch4j` и прочих подобных.

Знаю например, что можно так менять некоторые параметры:

```java
System.setProperty("sun.net.client.defaultConnectTimeout", "5000");
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Вы можете использовать [JMX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/index.html). Эта технология позволяет мониторить состояние JVM, а также менять некоторые параметры.

Также вы может использовать ее для управления своим приложением. Для этого вам надо будет реализовать определенный набор интерфейсов.

Для до управления вы можете использовать утилиту **jconsole**

Answer (score 9):

Надеюсь, наведёт на нужные мысли:

[**System.getProperties()**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties()) - возвращает объект `Properties` с текущими значениями свойств системы.

[**System.setProperty()**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setProperty(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) - устанавливает системное свойство по заданному ключу.

[**System.getenv()**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv()) - возвращает карту текущих переменных окружения. Менять их нельзя - можно пользоваться.